# Char(9) doesn't print tab in Sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, char

I am trying to print a tab in sql server using:

```
select 'tab-->' + char(9) + '<--tab'
```

But it doesn't seem to work and always prints

```
tab--> <--tab
```

Is there any thing I am missing?

Comment: Works fine for me.  Note that a tab character will go to the next tab stop in SQL Server, which may end up being only one or two spaces in practice.  Try copying and pasting the so-called `tab` character in another context and see if it generates tabs. (or put two or three tabs in your output string).

Comment: I copied the output to the notepad and same result.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you're testing this inside of Management Studio, the `Results to Grid` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>) setting will change your tab to a space... try switching to `Results to Text` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)  instead, and you will see the tab.

Alternately, you can change your `select` to a `print`:

```
print 'tab-->' + char(9) + '<--tab'
```

Outputs...

```
tab-->  <--tab
```

Comment: I tested "select '>' + char(9) + '<'" with results to grid and still get a tab.

Comment: @BenThul On what version of SSMS?  I tested in SSMS 2005 and I don't get the tab with results to grid...

Answer (score 1):

1. Tool -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Grid -> Retain CR/LF on copy or save
2. Restart SSMS

Answer (score 0):

The thing about tabs is that they aren't a constant width. A tab character says "bring me to the next tab stop". If you currently have tab stops set at eight characters and the tab is at character six, the tab will only be one wide. But let's say you're skeptical (a good thing!). There's more evidence that the tab is actually being output. If you do something like `print '>' + char(9) + '<'`, you'll notice that you can't select only one space in the gap, indicating that the whitespace that you're seeing is atomic. But more convincing to me is to paste it into an editor that allows you to see tabs. I use vim, but use whatever you like. In all cases I tested, the tab character showed up.

Answer (score 0):

Each `Char(9)` or `char(160)` is converted to a space.
If you align char(9)+char(9)+char(9) => you still got only 1 space.

So I tried these :

```
<"something"+char(9)+char(160)+char(9)+char(160)+char(9)+char(160)+char(9)+char(160)"something">
```

returns `something[8 spaces here]something` (each char9 or char16 is replaced by a space)

Visually, I got what I wanted...